# Are there ways to react upon a click without adding an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, dom-events, nvda

I'm using this great Chrome extension [Visual Event](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visual-event/pbmmieigblcbldgdokdjpioljjninaim) which displays JS events attached to a website's elements visually.

Using it, I noticed that there seem to be other ways to react upon a click using JavaScript that aren't events?

For example, the following page has a dialog programmed in JavaScript, but Visual Event doesn't show any events:

https://media-mediatemple.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/accessible.html

[image]

When looking at the source code, I see it uses `.addEventListener` (a plain JS function?) instead of `.click` (a jQuery function?). I created a demo page with both variants:

http://codepen.io/jmuheim/pen/jqBodO

[image]

But this doesn't seem to be the only difference. Because when I use a screenreader like [NVDA](http://www.nvaccess.org/), it announces `clickable` for elements that react upon clicks - but it doesn't do this in any case, as it seems.

In the first example (the modal window), NVDA doesn't say `clickable` at all:

[image]

In my example, NVDA announces `clickable` for both elements:

[image]

So I'm really confused about the different ways to react upon a click in JavaScript, as there seem to be at least 3 different types:

- One using `.click`, which is always announced by NVDA as `clickable` and displayed by Visual Event
- One using `.addEventListener` being announced by NVDA (and not displayed by Visual Event)
- One using `.addEventListener` not being announced by NVDA (and not displayed by Visual Event)

Can anybody tell me the differences here? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are several questions,

Actually in your first example, there **wasn't** any click event bind to the form.

It's simply use the html `submit` button to submit the form. Below is the source code from that demo.

```
<form>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="input" placeholder="Gimmie ur Name">

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" class="input" placeholder="Gimmie ur Email">

    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit Form">
  </form>
```

And here is the [Form sample code from w3school.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit)

`.addEventListener` and `.onclick` are pure javascript function. `.click` is defined by jQuery.

[addEventListener from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

[onclick from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onclick)

[.click from Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

For the differences between the **Visual Event** and **NVDA** that's how Visual Event catch your event. (click only?)

Hope this would solve your questions.